# jQuery: Adding to an element's event

Tags: jquery

Is it possible in jQuery to add an element's event?  For example if I wanted to add a .fadeIn() to an element when it is clicked but also retain any other functionality that may already exist (given that I do not know if there is or isn't currently anything firing on click).

Answer (score 6):

jQuery doesn't overwrite events, it adds to them. So if you did:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").click(function () { $(this).append("test<br />"); });
    $("#test").click(function () { $(this).append("test 2<br />"); });
});
```

with a div looking like:

```
<div id="test">click me <br /></div>
```

When you click on the div, it will append "test" and "test 2" at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to have multiple events mapped to the same element right?

Yes, it is possible. The order it will run might be a bit unpredictable, but you can have them.